# How to improve an RDF document?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

Am building a catalog of chemicals. The example below is 2,4-D (a pesticide).

The long term goal is to combine many RDF files into an OWL "catalog" with reasoning capabilities.

The short term objective is to build one RDF file at a time.

Then, when RDF files are combined into an OWL catalog, will add new relationships and rules for reasoning.

My short term approach below is:

1. Declare ontologies.
2. Use SKOS to set Concept.
3. Use DBpedia to set broad term.
4. Use DBpedia to set exact term.
5. Identify exact and similar items.
6. Define a Resource map and Aggregation.
7. Itemize aggregation.

Here is the RDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:agrontology="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:cheminf="http://semantiscience.org/resource/"
  xmlns:dbp="http://dbpedia.org/resource/"
  xmlns:ore="http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/">
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance">
    <ore:aggregatedBy rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance#Aggregation" />
  </skos:Concept>
  <ore:aggregates rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance">
    <cheminf:CHEMINF_000266>chemical substance</cheminf:CHEMINF_000266>
  </ore:aggregates>
  <ore:ResourceMap rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance#ResourceMap">
    <ore:describes rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance#Aggregation" />
  </ore:ResourceMap>
  <dbp:Chemical rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid">
    <schema:name>2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic acid</schema:name>
  </dbp:Chemical>
  <cheminf:CHEMINF_000140 rdf:about="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/compound/CID1486">
    <schema:name>PubChem CID:1486</schema:name>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical"/>
  </cheminf:CHEMINF_000140>
  <dbp:Chemical rdf:about="http://id.loc.gov/authorities/subjects/sh85037669">
    <schema:name>LCSH:85037669</schema:name>
    <skos:closeMatch>
      <cheminf:CHEMINF_000140 rdf:about="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/compound/CID1486">
        <schema:name>PubChem CID:1486</schema:name>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical"/>
      </cheminf:CHEMINF_000140>
    </skos:closeMatch>
  </dbp:Chemical>
  <dbp:Chemical rdf:about="http://lod.nal.usda.gov/nalt/1353">
    <schema:name>NALT:1353</schema:name>
    <schema:sameAs rdf:resource="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/compound/CID1486"/>
  </dbp:Chemical>
  <dbp:Chemical rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_8543">
    <schema:name>Agrovoc:8543</schema:name>
    <schema:sameAs rdf:resource="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/compound/CID1486"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#hasCodeAgrovoc"/>
  </dbp:Chemical>
  <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance#Aggregation">
    <ore:describedBy rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chemical_substance#ResourceMap" />
    <ore:aggregates rdf:resource="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/compound/CID1486" />
    <ore:aggregates rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_8543" />
    <ore:aggregates rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid" />
    <ore:aggregates rdf:resource="http://id.loc.gov/authorities/subjects/sh85037669" />
    <ore:aggregates rdf:resource="http://lod.nal.usda.gov/nalt/1353" />
  </ore:Aggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

How can I improve on this approach? For example:

1. Add more expressive relationships.
2. Make it more compact.
3. Establish provenance (using http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/) for an Ontology; an
   Authority; an item?
4. Better organize the file for combining with other RDF files into an OWL environment?

Thank you for your help here.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to combine RDF and OWL? The RDF-serialization of OWL is not particularly nice. Also, SKOS is a little bit like "poor man's OWL", how and why would you want to combine them?  What are the use-cases for the end-result of what you create? Do you really need provenance? Of what exactly? Why?

Comment: The thought is to start small (RDF assertions) and then aggregate them in an OWL DL environment to express more complex relationships among the items. Can certainly use alternative ontologies (alternatives to SKOS, for example) if that creates problems down the road. A sample use case is: a "Plant" (specific species) "hasPest" (specific species) where Plant "isProtectedBy" "Chemical" within "Limits" (a numeric range) set by "Regulation" in "Region."

Comment: That sounds reasonable but to me it seems like at some point you would have to migrate your data from RDF/S to OWL, would that be ok? The example you gave would be covered by simple RDF/S I guess. Anyway, I was wondering more about how do you imagine to use the result in the real world? What problems are you trying to solve? What tools do you have in mind? Do you need some kind of reasoning? Is it done for the purpose of exchanging data in a unified format?

Comment: Yes, migration from RDF/S to OWL is the plan. There are two application. (1) Getting all objects, object properties, etc properly modeled in OWL ("is the model correct?"). (2) generating machine readable "labels" that automate industrial equipment. Provenance is important because we need to associate the assertion of a "fact" with an "Authority." Right now, we want to do simple provenance (per above).

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think that as stated it's too broad for a single Stack Overflow question: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."  I think you could make this into a handful of on-topic questions, though, by taking each of your example improvements, showing an example of the sort of improved output you'd like, and asking about how you might get it.

Comment: I think you are on a good way:) It's difficult to recommend something without knowing more about the domain. The only thing I find a little confusing is that your example RDF document states that dbpedia:Chemical_substance#Aggregation is an aggregation and aggregates all the other chemicals mentioned in the document. Should the subject really be dbpedia:Chemical_substance#Aggregation? I would instead expect some instance URL to express that the specific aggregation (and not the DbPedia aggregation concept) consists of the listed chemicals.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor - Roger that. Will break it down into separate topics: syntax correctness; how to add provenance; etc.

Comment: @jkbkot Lemme think about that. My thought was to start with a class-type URI (the DBpedia "class" Chemical_substance) and then aggregate instances to that base#Aggregation.

Comment: Btw, when you create the new answers, please include RDF for example as N3 rather than RDF/XML. You can comfortably convert your snippets here: http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/

Comment: @jkbkot Roger that - I use that tool; it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that questions #2 and #4 can be addressed by considering the idea of removing schema-style elements from your representation. The data that you provided seems to mix the definition of domain concepts (ie: that a `ChemicalSubstance` is a `Concept`) with instance information (`http://dbpedia.org/resource/2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid http://schema.org/name "2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic acid"`). A best practice here would be to keep a single vocabulary/ontology for describing the backbone structures that you'll be using to represent the instance data for individual chemicals.

I'd also like to note at a superficial level, it seems that you may not be consistently using `rdf:type` to define class membership. Additionally, you may be using `rdf:type` where you'd probably instead prefer to have [`rdfs:subClassOf`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_subclassof).

I would suggest storing each of these different documents within a named graph of a [RDF dataset](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-concepts-20140225/#section-dataset). Create a meaningful IRI for each chemical graph using some consistent convention.

The simplest approach to #3 (provenance information) could be to store triples describing an `owl:Ontology` (the `x` in [these examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Extracting_Declarations_and_the_IRIs_of_the_Directly_Imported_Ontology_Documents)) stored with each document (named graph). This follows existing conventions, but can break down if you combine named graphs (as the triples for each graph would not be necessarily annotated to describe what ontology contained them). A minor variation, down to preferences, would be to store provenance information within the default graph of your data-store in order to separate chemical meta information from descriptions.